# Multiple conditions using if not in <string> continue error

Tags: python, string, if-statement, text

I am parsing a plain text file that has several pieces of information in different lines. This is a sample of a line:
DEBUG[2017-01-01 23:00:04.264][TX ID:201701010AEBD4] [Core Process] [user promo status:0]
  Each line had different details and therefore I want to multiple lines each time.

I use the code as follow:

```
if not "mystring" in line: continue
queryA = line.split(':')
queryB = line.split('=')
print(queryA, queryB)

Output:
queryA queryB
```

Now, this is my first line(in the file), I want to go to another line which has a different condition and retrieve few pieces. When I do the following:

```
if not "mystring" in line: continue
queryA = line.split(':')
queryB = line.split('=')
print(queryA, queryB)
if not "my 2nd string" in line: continue
queryC = line.split(':')
queryD = line.split('=')
print(queryC, queryD)

Output:
queryA
```

I want to see this output:

```
queryA queryB queryC queryD
```

What would be a better way to make this better and prints all the statements?

Comment: Can you show us what the file contains?

Comment: Also, please fix the code indentation

Comment: I have used the same indentation. Actually, this is how it should be if you used if not in. The file has log details where I perform regular expression to extract the details. Lines look like this: DEBUG[2017-01-01 23:00:04.264][TX ID:201701010AEBD4] [Core Process] [user promo status:0]